# Facebook Black Screen When Signing In

Tags: facebook-graph-api, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to use the flutter_facebook_login and every time I click the button associated with the method I get a dimmed screen but, no facebook log in page.

I have updated to the latest version of the dependency and not sure where is the issue.

```
 dependencies:
  flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.0
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  json_annotation: ^2.0.0




void initiateFacebookLogin() async {
    var facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();

    var facebookLoginResult = await facebookLogin
        .logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 'public_profile']);
    switch (facebookLoginResult.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        print("Error");
        onLoginStatusChanged(false);
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        print("CancelledByUser");
        onLoginStatusChanged(false);
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        final token = facebookLoginResult.accessToken.token;
        _token = token;

        // final graphResponse = await http.get(
        //     'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email&access_token=$token');

        // final profile = jsonDecode(graphResponse.body);
        // print(profile);
        print(_token);

        break;
    }
  }

  void userLogin(String token) {
    String grantType = '';
    String clientId = '';
    String clientSecret = '';
    String backend = '';
    String userType = '';

    final Map<String, dynamic> logIn = {
      'convert_token': grantType,
      'fLdfosdlfaisodfjaosdnaiscalsfa': clientId,
      'sdfasfasfererwa':
          clientSecret,
      'facebook': backend,
      _token: token,
      'customer': userType,
    };

    http
        .post('http://localhost:127.0.0.1/api/social/convert-token/',
            body: json.encode(logIn))
        .then((http.Response response) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      print(responseData);
    });
  }

  void backendToken() {
    setState(() {
      String token;

      print(token);
    });
  }

  bool isLoggedIn = false;

  void onLoginStatusChanged(bool isLoggedIn) {
    setState(() {
      this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
      print('User is logged in');
      userLogin(_token);

      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(new MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (BuildContext context) => NavigationPage()));
    });
  }
```

I want to sign into facebook when the function initiateFacebookLogin is called.